# Deserializing Encrypted ObjectList

Tags: java, android, deserialization, encryption

I can't catch exception on this code. Look in the code comments for clues. Apparently serialization worked fine so i won't paste serialization method code.

```
public class NewCipher {

    private static final String password = "somestatickey";
    private Cipher desCipher;
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private Context ctx;

    public NewCipher(Context ctx) throws Exception {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        // Create Key
        byte key[] = password.getBytes();
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        // Create Cipher
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

    }
```

**Tricky part starts here:**

```
public ArrayList<Category> loadCategories(){
    try {
        try {
            // Change cipher mode
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey); //some uncatchable exception seems to be appearing here

            // Create stream                
            FileInputStream fis;
            fis = ctx.openFileInput("categories.des");          
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, desCipher);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);

            try {
                // Read objects         
                ArrayList<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) ois.readObject(); //however the debugger goes right to this line and then goes to the finally, and then straight to final catch block
                return categories; //not beeing executed

            }
            finally {
                ois.close(); //debugger does a step here and then jumps to the end
            }   
        }
        catch(GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            Log.v("Debug", "Some message", ex); //not beeing executed
            return null; //not beeing executed  
        }           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Debug", "Some message", e); //not beeing executed
        return null; //actually the debugger jumps right here avoiding the log line above
    }
}
```

How do I know that problem is in line `desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);`? I was deleting line one by one, and always got same outcome. Something wrong must had been happening in the first line.

Unfortunatelly I'm not able to catch it, and for some reason code is trying to be executed further. I'm completly confused here. I tried `IOException` and `IllegalStateException` in place of `GeneralSecurityException`. Also tried to throw BadPaddingException. no logs though.

Please, I need an assistance on this.

Comment: that line `Log.v("Debug", "Some message", e);` tells you what exception it is. that's a first step

Comment: the problem is that line is not beeing executed

Comment: then catch a Throwable rather than an exception

Comment: How are you faring with this Jacek? Don't forget to followup on your own questions!

Comment: Still not resolved. Havent managed to find an answer for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Your key is not the right size, the code should throw an `InvalidKeyException`, which is of type GeneralSecurityException. Make sure your code compiles and is in sync with the generated class files before debugging.

Note that you should never use a String as password, should never use getBytes() without specifying the encoding, should not use DES, should not use ECB mode (etc. etc.).